# Homework Problem, Definiteness Hessian, Undefined Major Minor

Tags: optimization, hessian-matrix

We are supposed to determine local extrema of:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + xy
$$

Here is what I've done so far:

1. Calculate the gradient of $f$:

$$
\nabla f(x,y) = (-\frac{1}{x^2} + y, -\frac{1}{y^2} + x) 
$$
2) Determine $\nabla f  = \mathbf(0)$:

Neccessary optimality condition:
$$
\nabla f(x_0,y_0)  \overset{!}{=} \mathbf(0) \Rightarrow (x_0,y_0) = (0,0) 
$$

3. Determine Hessian of $f$ in $(0,0)$:

$$
H = 
\bigg(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{x^3} &1 \\
1 &\frac{1}{y^3}
\end{matrix}
\bigg)
$$

evaluated at $(0,0)$:

$$
H = 
\bigg(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{0} &1 \\
1 &\frac{1}{0}
\end{matrix}
\bigg)
$$

where $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined. So how can i determine the definitness of the matrix, when a major minor is not defined.

My intuition is that since non of definetness conditions are fulfilled, the Hessian is indefinite. Since it is indefinete, there is no extrema in this point.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: I did not understand why $x_0$ and $y_0$ should be $0$. $\nabla f(1,1) =0$, right? Moreover, are you looking for global _minima_ and _maxima_? Because the function seems not to be bounded, e.g. $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,+\infty)} f(x,y)= +\infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0^-)}f(x,y)=-\infty $$

Comment: You are right! But then i still need to check the behavior at (0,0) as well, bc the condition is fulfilled at that point. Just edited to main text. We are looking for local extrema.

Comment: But  $(0,0)$ does not belong to the domain of your function, right?

Comment: Year! You are right, it's not in the domain! Please make it an answer so I can upvote and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to evalute the hessian matrix in $(0,0)$, since this point it is not in the domain of your function.